# Separation of peaks

Tags: approximation-theory

Could you please give any reference to literature on "separation o peaks", i.e. approximation of a numerically given function by a linear combination of two or several Gaussians with unknown parameters? Or, maybe there exists a theory covering a more general class of functions (not only Gaussians)?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extensive literature on "separation of peaks", under the technical name "Multivariate Curve Resolution". This is a 2013 [review](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003267012018351) [paywall] and this is a 2006 [review](http://www.iasbs.ac.ir/chemistry/chemometrics/history/7th/chapt.11.multivariate.curve.resolution.pdf) [free download]. Software that will do this for you is available [here.](https://mcrals.wordpress.com)

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, I am interested in the mathematical background, and not in software. (Actually, I wonder if I can contribute something as a mathematician.)

Comment: the 2006 review is oriented towards the mathematical background